# correct way of using resilience4j with WebClient

Tags: kotlin, spring-webclient, resilience4j

I am writing a circuitbreaker wrapper which should encapsulate http calls (using Spring WebClient ). All the integration services would call the invokeService() method which in turn calls excecute().

Now, if execute() is successful, fine. If not, circuitbreaker should trigger after n failures( based on configurations). This is what I have done. Not sure if this would work( because of Mono) and the right way to do it.

```
@Service
class CircuitBreakerWrapper @Inject constructor(cbService: CircuitBreakerService?)
                                    : BaseHttpExcecutor() {

   private var cbService = cbService

     fun <R> invokeService(
             service: String,
             webClient: WebClient, 
             HttpRequestSpec httpRequestSpec,
             cbProperties: CircuitBreakerProperties?,
             type: Class<R>?): Mono<R> {

        val circuitBreaker = cbService
                .registerCircuitBreaker(serviceName, properties)

         val supplier: Supplier<Mono<R>> = Supplier {
            execute(webClient, httpRequestSpec, type)
        }
        val decoratedSupplier = CircuitBreaker
                .decorateSupplier(circuitBreaker, supplier)
        return Try.ofSupplier(decoratedSupplier).get()
    }
}
```

This is what execute() looks like:

```
webClient.method(HttpMethod.GET)
     .uri(url, params)
     .retrieve()
     .bodyToMono(response)
```

Comment: Looks correct in theory. The example here - https://reflectoring.io/circuitbreaker-with-resilience4j/ uses it similarly.

Comment: does this implementaion work?